# Slow aggregation: sorting documents according to filtered + nested objects

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My documents look like this:

```
docs = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'xs': [
            {'name': 'foo', 'value': 0.5},
            {'name': 'bar', 'value': 0.3},
        ],
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'xs': [
            {'name': 'foo', 'value': 0.9},
            {'name': 'bar', 'value': 0.1},
        ],
    },
]
```

I would like get the top N documents (descending sort + limit) according to their `xs.value`, for each `xs.name` value individually.

I tried to do this with `$unwind` and `$sort` however it feels somewhat slow. I have ~6000 docs and each of them have 20 elements in `xs`, and it takes about 3 minutes for the following aggregation:

```
steps = [
  {'$match': query},
  {'$unwind': '$xs'},
  {'$match': {'xs.name': "foo"}},
  {'$sort': {'xs.value': -1}},
  {'$limit': 10}
]
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up? I'm thinking I could write the aggregation in many ways but I'm not sure which has the best potential for speedup.

Thanks!

Edit:
The following steps:

```
{'$match': {**query, 'xs.name': "foo"}},
{'$unwind': '$xs'},
{'$match': {'xs.name': "foo"}},
{'$limit': 1},
```

takes about a minute to complete, without even sorting

Indices look like:

```
 'xs.name': {'v': 2, 'key': [('xs.name', 1)]},
 'xs.value-1': {'v': 2, 'key': [('xs.value', -1)]}}
```

Edit 2:
Another attempt:

```
{'$match': query},
{'$project': {
     'items': {
     '$filter': {'input': '$xs', 'as': 'this', 'cond': {'$eq': ['$$this.name', "foo"]}}
},
}},
{'$limit': 1},
```

Is very fast, but adding this:

```
{'$sort': {'xs.value': -1}},
```

before the `$limit` makes it quite slow.

Comment: You may want to put your `{'$match': {'xs.name': "foo"}}` into the first `$match` for a more selective query. Another thing is can you give us your current indexes so that we can see what we can help?

Comment: You're right but in my use case all objects will have each value of `xs.name`. The reason I don't use these as straight up document fields is because they may change frequently / be queried in various ways.

I have an ascending index on `xs.name` but I think I am missing an index on `xs.value`.

Comment: @eloaf, As @ray pointed out, I think your `$match` condition is the bottleneck. Frequent document change wont be a problem as far as I know, you have to add `xs.name` too in match condition as pointed out. Can you provide the value if `query` variable so that we can suggest an index accordingly

Comment: Thanks I've edited my original question with some additional information

Comment: I think the `$unwind` could be making the situation more complicated. If querying on the innermost `xs` array entries level, you may want to consider to refactor the collection to store the array entries as individual documents, like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xwc5SEIW5OS). Indexing and querying at the `xs` level will be much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works very fast without $sort because there are no blocking stages, means cursor get results as soon as pipline processed the first batch, and with $limit it doesn't need to process the rest of the documents.

Blocking stages like $sort and $group require previous stage to process all documents before the pipeline can continue.

A word about how indices are used in aggregation from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes :

> the following pipeline stages can take advantage of indexes:
>
> **$match**
>
> The $match stage can use an index to filter documents if it occurs at the beginning of a pipeline.
>
> **$sort**
>
> The $sort stage can use an index as long as it is not preceded by a $project, $unwind, or $group stage.

Which means no use of "xs.name" index after $unwind and in-memory sort for "xs.value" which makes the pipeline even slower.

I'm afraid the only way to benefit from indexes is to change structure of the documents - split the collection to 2, remove "xs" array from "docs" and keep subdocumnets in a separate doc_xs collection:

```
docs = [
    {
        'id': 1
    },
    {
        'id': 2
    },
]

doc_xs = [
    {'name': 'foo', 'value': 0.5, 'doc_id':1},
    {'name': 'bar', 'value': 0.3, 'doc_id':1},
    {'name': 'foo', 'value': 0.9, 'doc_id':2},
    {'name': 'bar', 'value': 0.1, 'doc_id':2}
]
```

The aggregation will be:

```
doc_xs.aggregate([
  {$match: {"name": "foo"}},
  {$sort: {"value": -1}},
  {$limit: 10},
  {$lookup: {
    from: "docs",
    localField: "doc_id",
    foreignField: "id",
    as: "doc"
  }}
])
```

It can benefit from compound index `{"name":1, "value":-1}` on doc_xs collection and `{"id": 1}` on docs